# MVC5 Which one should I use to create new users : Register in AccountController or Create User in ApplicationUserController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm coding a MVC5 With Identity (EntityFramework). I have been provided 2 ways to create a user:
Register in the AccountController(Default when you implement Identity 1.0) OR Create in ApplicationUser(Default when you add a controller)

The problem is which one should I be using? AccountController Register method OR ApplicationUser Create Method(Default from adding a controller)?

**REGISTER WAY provided by default Identity 1.0**

[image]

AccountsViewModel.cs

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepotList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentList { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

}
```

AccountController.cs

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public AccountController()       
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
        ConfigureRegisterViewModel(model);
        ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName");
        ViewBag.DepotID = new SelectList(db.Depots, "DepotID", "DepotName");
        return View(model);
    }
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfigureRegisterViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = new ApplicationUser() {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Email = model.Email,
                FirstMidName = model.FirstMidName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                EnrollmentDate = model.EnrollmentDate,
                DepotID = model.DepotID,
                DepartmentID = model.DepartmentID
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    private void ConfigureRegisterViewModel(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        IEnumerable<Department> departments = db.Departments.OrderBy(u => u.DepartmentName);
        model.DepotList = departments.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.DepartmentID.ToString(),
            Text = a.DepartmentName.ToString()
        });
        IEnumerable<Depot> depots = db.Depots.OrderBy(u => u.DepotName);
        model.DepotList = depots.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.DepotID.ToString(),
            Text = a.DepotName.ToString()
        });
    }
```

}

**APPLICATION USER CREATE WAY by default adding controller**

ApplicationUserController.cs

```
    public class ApplicationUserController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        // GET: ApplicationUser/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName");
            ViewBag.DepotID = new SelectList(db.Depots, "DepotID", "DepotName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: ApplicationUser/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,IsAdministrator,LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate,DepartmentID,DepotID,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(applicationUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

   //         ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName", applicationUser.DepartmentID);
   //         ViewBag.DepotID = new SelectList(db.Depots, "DepotID", "DepotName", applicationUser.DepotID);
            return View(applicationUser);
        }

    }
```

ApplicationUser.cs(Model)

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager
            .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstMidName + " " + LastName; }
    }
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
    public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't mention your problem here.

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan The problem is which one should I be using? AccountController Register method OR ApplicationUser Create Method(Default from adding a controller)?

Answer (score 1):

This depends up on you like wise,if you are managing your user through identity management you can use account controller,if you have your own security library to manage user most likely you can do it on different controller.this all depends on you your functionality for your user management like

1] session login

```
Or
```

2] cookie based login

Comment: If I look at the definition of IdentityUser they have properties like `AccessFailedCount`,`Claims`, `EmailConfirmed` and `SecurityStamp` etc. If I use the account controller then I won't be able to set any of these properties when I create a user. How will I add these features if I were to use the account controller's way to create a new user.

Comment: If you dont' need those fields. allow null value to that fields This will solve the  issue minimum u need to insert username and pwd@TykiMikk

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that CRUD version as is, or at all - for self service allow people to use the register method and extend the functionality **behind** the controller if you need to carry out additional work or set more properties. 
The auto scaffolded version is basically giving you a start and is intended for new view models rather than framework classes like identity user ;  by exposing that method anyone can create themselves a new administrator account, even if you remove the fields to set this from the view.   You should follow the guidance in the comment and remove binding to any properties you don't want to allow users (or hackers) to set directly and you should also implement access control within the controllers action.  At the very least create a new view model class to represent your views data instead of using identity model - and then hey presto your controller, view and model will look much closer to the account controllers implementation...